# Highlight duplicated values in many cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, gs-conditional-formatting

I have dozens of columns where I want to highlight duplicates. I have an issue with the formula. Here is what I have:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B,$C$3:$C,$D$3:$D,$E3:$E,$F3:$F,$G$3:$G,$H$3:$H,$I$3:$I,$J$3:$J,$K$3:$K,$L$3:$L,$M$3:$M,$N$3:$N,$O$3:$O,$P$3:$P,$Q$3:$Q)>1
```

I have also tried this:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B,$B3:$B,$C$3:$C,$C3:$C,$D$3:$D,$D3:$D,$E$3:$E,$E3:$E,$F$3:$F,$F3:$F,$G$3:$G,$G3:$G,$H$3:$H,$H3:$H,$I$3:$I,$I:$I,$J$3:$J,$J3:$J,$K$3:$K,$K3:$K,$L$3:$L,$L3:$L,$M$3:$M,$M3:$M,$N$3:$N,$N3:$N,$O$3:$O,$O3:$O,$P$3:$P,$P3:$P,$Q$3:$Q,$Q3:$Q)>1
```

Google sheets says: Invalid formula. What is wrong with it? Is there an easy way of doing it instead of typing all the columns one by one?

Comment: Hello, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899516/how-to-highlight-cell-if-value-duplicate-in-same-column-for-google-spreadsheet?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas. No it does not. I want to go through all selected columns, not only the one. Also every cell has no relation with any other.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski It does answer your question, or please provide a test sheet so the difference could be seen.

Comment: You need to set the custom formula for conditional formatting for the range `B3:Q` to `=COUNTIF($B$3:$Q, B3) > 1`. Looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/j59RSPA.png).

Comment: Thanks @kishkin ! This sorts out the problem. As I have a lot of data and want to make sure it works ok - my data starts from B3 and ends on S22 - is this the right formula(?): =COUNTIF($B3:$S,B3)>1 (applied to B3:S22) ?

Comment: Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1STyN8JiWXR5HBvCtmeUeesKJWWWxNuuy4VkS__dDq5k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski If you want to check everything from row 3 to the very bottom then use `=COUNTIF($B$3:$S, B3) > 1` applied to `B3:S`. If you want to handle only the range `B3:S22` then apply to it `=COUNTIF($B$3:$S$22, B3) > 1`. Do not forget those `$`s.

Comment: Thank you. This is great @kishkin. All works perfectly. I don't know if I can accept the answer in comments, but I would most certainly do if you post this as an answer. Cheers

Comment: Why someone downvoted my question? I can't see the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a custom formula for conditional formatting.

If you want to check everything from row 3 to the very bottom then use

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$S, B3) > 1
```

applied to `B3:S`.

If you want to handle only the range `B3:S22` then apply to it:

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$S$22, B3) > 1
```

Do not forget those `$`s.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(""&B3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $B$25:$B$28))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I think OP just meant to manually show those "data1-4" as the duplicates that are there, not the list of strings to search for.